# Java static/global variables in Spring Rest Application

Tags: java, spring, rest, static, global-variables

I'm working on a Spring Rest Service Web application where as soon as a HTTP request is received in the controller, I set a `static String` variable `null`. Further in application, this variable is modified multiple times by various classes and methods, and in the end, this is returned as REST service response.

I'm afraid that this `static String` variable might be updated by another concurrent HTTP request resulting in incorrect value in previous request.

I don't wish to use instance variable as that would need to be passed to multiple methods (>30) across the application.

Please, suggest a way to declare a global variable which is not updated by any concurrent HTTP request and have a separate copy for each HTTP request.

Comment: You could try using a `ThreadLocal`, but if you need to pass around an object to over 30 methods, you have a problem with your design. You're correct that the static global variable isn't going to work.

Comment: I'm creating a XML file validator application which has more than 100 unique fields. There are multiple methods(>30) to validate different kind of unique XML tags. I take a static StringBuilder object at the start of validation and keeps updating that object whenever an error has occurred. In the end, returns that StringBuilder object which has information of all the errors.

Comment: There are no global variables in Java. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes @EJP. I'm aware that there are no global variables in Java. I'm looking for an alternative which I can use in my scenario. I don't want to use instance variable as that variable need to go through more than 30 methods and keep passing a variable through these many methods is a tedious task.

Comment: So why did you mention them in your title and your question? There's no point in talking about things that don't exist. Please amend.

Answer (score 1):

All your validation methods already take a parameter, right? The data to be validated.

They also all need the ability to generate validation messages and store them somewhere, e.g. in a "result collector", right? So that should be a parameter too.

*Side note: Giving both the data and the result collector to the validators as parameters allows you to **unit test** the validators.*

I don't see the problem with passing the result collector around to all the validators, the same way you're passing the data to be validated around. It's how the code should have been written to begin with.

Never use "global" memory in a web application.

Viewed purely from a validators point of view, you pass in the data to be validated, but expect the result to be written to a static collector? **Bad design**, right there. The validator should not be responsible for figuring out how to find the result collector.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for your suggestion. Thinking of changing the design with using instance variables.

Comment: @gaity Instance variables on what object(s)? Your beans? They are singletons, so the instance variables are too, and you've gained nothing.

Comment: I'll create a bean with scope prototype and put result collector into that. Further, inject this bean in my singleton controller using lookup method. does this approach look fine?

Comment: Why use bean at all. A regular Java class will do fine. It is the controller that needs the result collector, since it is the one that needs to understand the results, right?

Comment: Yes, that would also work. I can create StringBuilder object in controller method and keep passing it further in the application for collecting results.

Answer (score 0):

The controller has a singleton scope, it should not contain a data. If you need to store data to to the application use the corresponding scope of the bean containing the data string.

If you are using a bean which is shared among other users then the data should be protected from concurrent modifications. Which way you provide the protection to users is not important at the moment but affordable data structures simplify the implementation of such beans.